# Windows shortcut that runs through DosBox

Tags: windows, shortcuts, dosbox

Is there a way to make a Windows shortcut that will run a dos program through DosBox automatically, without the need to open DosBox mount a drive etc' manually?
So opening the shortcut loads the program (through DosBox) without the need for any additional input.

I'm using Win7 and Dosbox 0.74.

P.S.
I'm not interested in installing a macros program that will do the process.
If there's a built-in way, I'd like to know, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this page](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBoxShortcuts) should have everything you need.
The long and short of it is basically you create a shortcut that points to your DOSBox install, then has as arguments -conf and the path to the config file for running that game with settings you like, then the path to the game.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to place everything you need in the [autoexec] portion of the configuration file.

I use the SVN-Daum version of DOSBox from http://ykhwong.x-y.net/

```
#     dosbox-SVN-Daum.conf
#     C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox SVN-Daum\TOOLS\Run DOSBox configuration.bat

[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
mount c c:\WhereMyGameIsAt
c:
Game.BAT
```

Works for me.  Then you just need a desktop shortcut for DOSBox, and your game will open automatically.  Of course, this customizes your DOSBox for one game only, but hey.